Can't install nano on Ubuntu 22.04
I mostly have no idea what I'm doing.
I have broken my Ubuntu virtual machine while trying to setup a dedicated server.
It all started because I was unable to install Wine, but at some point even my nano got removed and now I cannot install it back. I even tried to install it manually, but dependencies are broken.
This is how my sources.list looks like now:
deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe main
deb-src [arch=amd64,i386] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe main

deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe main
deb-src [arch=amd64,i386] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe main

deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security universe main
deb-src [arch=amd64,i386] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security universe main

deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports universe main
deb-src [arch=amd64,i386] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports universe main

deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy partner
deb-src [arch=amd64,i386] http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy partner

My architectures:
dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
  armhf
  i386
  amd64
dpkg --print-architecture
  arm64

And finally the error while installing nano:
sudo apt install nano
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt : Depends: adduser but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: gpgv or
                gpgv2 but it is not going to be installed or
                gpgv1
       Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 2.4.8) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
       Depends: libgcc-s1 (>= 3.3.1) but it is not installable
       Depends: libgnutls30 (>= 3.7.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libseccomp2 (>= 2.4.2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 11) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libsystemd0 but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: ca-certificates but it is not going to be installed
 base-files : PreDepends: awk
              Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
 base-passwd : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
               Depends: libdebconfclient0 (>= 0.145) but it is not going to be installed
 bash : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
        PreDepends: libtinfo6 (>= 6) but it is not installable
 bsdutils : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
            PreDepends: libsystemd0 but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: bsdextrautils
 coreutils : PreDepends: libacl1 (>= 2.2.23) but it is not going to be installed
             PreDepends: libattr1 (>= 1:2.4.44) but it is not going to be installed
             PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
             PreDepends: libgmp10 (>= 2:6.2.1+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
             PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
 dash : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
 debianutils : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
 diffutils : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
 dpkg : PreDepends: libbz2-1.0 but it is not going to be installed
        PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
        PreDepends: liblzma5 (>= 5.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
        PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
        PreDepends: libzstd1 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
        PreDepends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
 e2fsprogs : PreDepends: libblkid1 (>= 2.36) but it is not going to be installed
             PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
             PreDepends: libcom-err2 (>= 1.43.9) but it is not going to be installed
             PreDepends: libext2fs2 (= 1.46.5-2ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
             PreDepends: libss2 (>= 1.38) but it is not going to be installed
             PreDepends: libuuid1 (>= 2.16) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: logsave
             Recommends: e2fsprogs-l10n but it is not going to be installed
 findutils : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
             PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
 grep : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
        PreDepends: libpcre3 but it is not going to be installed
 gzip : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
 hostname : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
 init : PreDepends: systemd-sysv
 libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (> 2.35) but it is not installable
            Depends: libc6 (< 2.36) but it is not installable
 libcrypt1 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.25) but it is not installable
 libcrypt1:armhf : Depends: libc6:armhf (>= 2.25) but it is not installable
 login : PreDepends: libaudit1 (>= 1:2.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
         PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
         PreDepends: libpam0g (>= 0.99.7.1) but it is not going to be installed
         PreDepends: libpam-runtime but it is not going to be installed
         PreDepends: libpam-modules but it is not going to be installed
 ncurses-bin : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
               PreDepends: libtinfo6 (>= 6.3) but it is not installable
 perl-base : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.35) but it is not installable
 sed : PreDepends: libacl1 (>= 2.2.23) but it is not going to be installed
       PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
       PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
 sysvinit-utils : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
 tar : PreDepends: libacl1 (>= 2.2.23) but it is not going to be installed
       PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
       PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
 util-linux : PreDepends: libaudit1 (>= 1:2.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libblkid1 (>= 2.37.2) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
              PreDepends: libcap-ng0 (>= 0.7.9) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libmount1 (>= 2.37.2) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libpam0g (>= 0.99.7.1) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libsmartcols1 (>= 2.34) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libsystemd0 but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libtinfo6 (>= 6) but it is not installable
              PreDepends: libudev1 (>= 183) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libuuid1 (>= 2.16) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

I was getting very similar, if not identical error while trying to install Wine earlier.
Is there a way to unscrew my Ubuntu now?

This question is similar to: What is the correct output of cat /etc/apt/sources.list?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If you are already using a virtual machine, then please don't use Wine. Use Windows apps on Windows host instead. That will keep Ubuntu error free as well.

It will be much easier, especially in a VM, to just reinstall and reload your data from backups. In future take a snapshot of the VM before performing dangerous actions. You can use wine just fine in an Ubuntu VM. But don't follow any wine instruction guides found on websites. Just install the version from the normal Ubuntu repos.

Thnak you guys for the input. I'm not running the VM locally, I connect to it via SSH. I have messed up spectacularly and after rebooting the instance fails to launch. Which means I need to start from scratch. As you say, I'm gonna be more careful now.
